# Unblock user interaction in fileWrapperOfType

Tags: macos, cocoa, osx-lion, nsdocument, nsfilewrapper

I would like to implement asynchronous saving in my NSDocument. According to the documentation, I need to return YES in [`canAsynchronouslyWriteToURL:ofType:forSaveOperation:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSDocument_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDocument/canAsynchronouslyWriteToURL%3aofType%3aforSaveOperation%3a) and then call [`unblockUserInteraction`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSDocument_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDocument/unblockUserInteraction) sometime during writing.

In my document, writing is performed by [`fileWrapperOfType:error:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSDocument_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDocument/fileWrapperOfType%3aerror%3a) by simply returning a NSFileWrapper.

```
- (NSFileWrapper*) fileWrapperOfType:(NSString *)typeName error:(NSError *__autoreleasing *)outError {
    return self.myMutableFileWrapper;
}
```

About this, the documentation says:

> For example, the default implementation of fileWrapperOfType:error:
>   invokes [unblockUserInteraction] when it has created the NSFileWrapper object to return.
>   Assuming that the NSFileWrapper is not mutated by subsequent user
>   actions, it is effectively a "snapshot" of the document's contents,
>   and once it is created it is safe to resume handling user events on
>   the main thread, even though some of those user events might change
>   the document's contents before the NSFileWrapper object has been
>   safely written.

Currently in my code `self.myMutableFileWrapper` can be changed after `fileWrapperOfType:error`, so I can't assume it won't be mutated like the documentation says.

Does this mean that I should modify `fileWrapperOfType:error:` to make a copy of my file wrapper, and then call `unblockUserInteraction`? Something like this:

```
- (NSFileWrapper*) fileWrapperOfType:(NSString *)typeName error:(NSError *__autoreleasing *)outError {
    NSFileWrapper *copyFileWrapper = MakeACopyOf(self.myMutableFileWrapper);
    [self unblockUserInteraction];
    return copyFileWrapper;
}
```

If the above is correct, how do I make a copy of a NSFileWrapper? Also, doesn't making a copy of a potentially huge NSFileWrapper negate the performance benefits of asynchronous saving?